# typescript, angular : unable to set value to class property, showing undefined property, while property is there

Tags: angular, typescript

I working in an Angular Application. I am really in stack situation.

**InterviewStatusRecommendation**

```
export class InterviewStatusRecommendation {
    public recommendationRequest: RecommendationRequest;
    public recommendationInfoList: RecommendationInfo[];
}
```

**RecommendationRequest**

```
export class RecommendationRequest {
    id: number;
    agentInitiationId: number;
    requestStatus: RecommendationRequestStatusEnum;
    accomplishDate: string;
    remarks: string;
}
```

**RecommendationInfo**

```
export class RecommendationInfo {
    id: number;
    agentInitiationId: number;
    sequenceId: number;
    userName: string;
    assignDate: string;
    recommendStatus: InterviewAccomplishmentStatusEnum;
    remarks: string;
    recommendationDate: string;
    isRequired: boolean;
    isActive: boolean;
}
```

Above is my three class. They are related to each other.
I am trying to create an object of `InterviewStatusRecommendation` type and trying to set value to its property but it is showing error.

**The code by which i am trying to set value.**

```
onSubmit (){

    const isRecommendation: InterviewStatusRecommendation = new InterviewStatusRecommendation();
            isRecommendation.recommendationRequest.agentInitiationId = this.agentInitiationId;
            isRecommendation.recommendationRequest.requestStatus = interviewStatus.interviewStatus;
            isRecommendation.recommendationRequest.remarks = interviewStatus.remarks;
            isRecommendation.recommendationRequest.accomplishDate = interviewStatus.invitationDate;
            interviewStatus.recommender.forEach(s => {
                const info = new RecommendationInfo();
                info.agentInitiationId = this.agentInitiationId;
                info.userName = s;
                isRecommendation.recommendationInfoList.push(info);
            });
}
```

**Error Log.**

```
core.js:5980 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'agentInitiationId' of undefined
    at RecommendationComponent.onSubmit (recommendation.component.ts:120)
    at RecommendationComponent_Template_form_ngSubmit_8_listener (recommendation.component.html:6)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:14994)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:15029)
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:25687)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at EventEmitter_.next (Subject.js:39)
```

My question is `agentInitiationId` property is inside the class. Then why it is undefined?

Comment: If the classes are only used to enforce type checking why not use TS [Interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) instead? It would remove instantiation of the class, and supports type assertion.

Answer (score 0):

`recommendationRequest` is undefined here which is a parent of `agentInitiationId`. Initialize it and then you can access the nested  fields as follows:

```
onSubmit (){

    const isRecommendation: InterviewStatusRecommendation = new InterviewStatusRecommendation();
    isRecommendation.recommendationRequest = new RecommendationRequest(); // initialize here
    isRecommendation.recommendationRequest.agentInitiationId = this.agentInitiationId;
    isRecommendation.recommendationRequest.requestStatus = interviewStatus.interviewStatus;
    isRecommendation.recommendationRequest.remarks = interviewStatus.remarks;
    isRecommendation.recommendationRequest.accomplishDate = interviewStatus.invitationDate;
    interviewStatus.recommender.forEach(s => {
       const info = new RecommendationInfo();
       info.agentInitiationId = this.agentInitiationId;
       info.userName = s;
       isRecommendation.recommendationInfoList.push(info);
    });
}
```